# Replacing MeeGo with Ubuntu on a netbook for development?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, meego

There's a netbook coming out that I'm interested in, the [ASUS Eee PC X101](http://www.asus.com/Eee/Eee_PC/Eee_PC_X101/), that comes with MeeGo pre-installed, but I'd prefer to wipe that OS and install Ubuntu.

Are there any issues I should consider before doing this? Is MeeGo more tuned for this kind of ultra-portable device, ie. cpu and battery life? My computing needs are modest, I usually run a terminal, text editor, and browser at the same time for web development, maybe some music playing as well.

The portability of this computer is attractive to me, but if I can't work on it, then it doesn't help me.

Comment: I don't see the need to do that, you can still have your browser, text editor an terminal running plus banshee (the player that comes with meego), it's as if you were working on fedora, now you can replace it with Ubuntu by just creating a liveusb and erasing the hard drive.

Comment: Good to know that option is available. I've never used MeeGo, so I haven't a clue about it's configuration and package management. I'm also very comfortable with Ubuntu and it's my preferred OS.

Comment: and let us know how you get on Marcus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having used both I am sure that you will more than fine. You could always try the meego installation for a little first and then if you do not like it download Ubuntu and try that perhaps from a pen drive and see what you prefer.

I have used both and they are both brilliant on a netbook. Ask perhaps yourself what you like about the Meego installation and then try the Ubuntu from a pen drive and see if there is any difference.

Meego can have some issues with wifi and graphics cards just like Ubuntu but as it is preinstalled it will be fine but you may need to be aware of them prior to any upgrades you do as that can get tricksy afterwards if your wifi or graphics card drivers need updating too. That said that can also be the same in Ubuntu. You can look both on here

[Meego Netbook Forum](http://forum.meego.com/forumdisplay.php?f=6)

and perhaps have a look at other sites and blogs to see what trouble and solutions people have with the hardware that is in this new Meego device. I did a Meego blog (check my profile for details) of common things I had to do.

I have to say I was pleased to see a netbook release of meego on hardware and this looks like a nice model.

I have no doubt that you will enjoy it and if you do not ...stick Ubuntu on. :)

Comment: I'm going to give MeeGo a chance. Without knowing anything about it, I was initially put-off by an "integrated solution"--usually that means I can't install the programs I want. But after a little research, it seems like a very open system, so I'm looking forward to trying it out. Thanks!

Comment: Well you have nothing to lose. I assume it is a linpus meego version which is really good.There is a good forums at the link above for meego netbooks with lots of faqs to get you started and more importantly able to change things. You can mess about with Meego quite alot in the end in my opinion to get it looking better. My blog (andybleadengoeskubuntu.blogspot.com) had a load of meego related items from when I used it so feel free to use that too.Lastly if you get really stuck contact me directly via email same name @gmail. Enjoy!